# Is this an appropriate use of labels and constraints in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j 2.1.1, running in server mode and accessed via the REST API from Java.   I last used 1.8, so I'm a little rusty and am trying to figure out the new features...

I'm building a graph of Twitter users, to see who follows whom. Each node will have a 'userid' property, which needs to be unique. Users fall into exactly one of three categories, A, B, or C.    I might query on things like "show me type C users who follow type A users"

My original plan was to create nodes labeled A, B, and C, and insert 'member_of' relationships for users of each type - and then I read about labels, which seemed like a win at first, but then I wasn't sure - I would create labels for A, B, and C, but I want userid to be unique across all categories, not just for users of a certain type.

Are labels my answer?  My 'meta-nodes'?  I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

```
// create a unique constraint
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:User) ASSERT u.userid IS UNIQUE;

// create a user

CREATE (u:User:A {userid:124});

// get or create a user
MERGE (u:User {userid:124}) ON CREATE SET u:A, u.created = timestamp();
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael!  Can the label be parameterized, or will I need to set it explicitly in the query string?  I can't find anything definitive in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Label is your answer. You'll create a seperate node for each user and each node will have its own label (A node can have multiple labels too). So essentially, you're marking each node with a label. You're not creating a layer of label under which you'll create some nodes. So your userids will remain unique globally. 
Hope it helps!